# Update the first row of table via sql

Tags: sql, date

I have a base table per_name :

```
start_date   end_date        type      name person_id 

01-jan-2016  02-Feb-2016      A         abc     1
03-Feb-2016  31-Dec-412       E         abc     1
```

Per_leg_data

```
start_date     end_date       leg_code    person_id 
31-Nov-2015    03-Mar-2016     SG            1
04-Mar-2016    31-Dec-4712     CG            1
```

Now what i want is that whenever the min(start_date) of name <>min(start_date) of leg_data then the first row of per_leg_data should be replaced by per_name min(start_date)

Something like :

```
If min(name.start_date) <> min(leg.start_date) 
then
update per_leg_data
set start_date = (select distinct min(start_date)
 from per_name pn 
where pn.person_id=person_id)
```

But this updating all the rows of the per_leg_data of date_start

Comment: where does person_id come from? it is not in your per_name table, is it?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me

Comment: Is the table structure fixed? It would be better to normalize the tables. Which are the primary keys in the tables for exmaple?

Comment: person_id is the primary key and these tables are date tracked so the structure is fixed

Comment: Are you sure peron_id is primary key? there are duplicate rows. it is not possible for person_id to be a PK.

Comment: @davadi - Yes becaue it is date tracked. I have to update minimun of date in leg data table

Comment: when you use person_id as a filter on the where clause... it affected to multiple rows... that is the problem. correct?
that is because the person_id is not unique

Comment: person_id has mutiple rows as one person record is date tracked it has history records. I want to change only the first row or the minimun effective start date row

Comment: @divya.trehan573 person_id cannot be the primary key alone. Impossible in relational database systems. Primary key values are unique; this is not the case in your example. I am not sure if you are familiar with the concepts of relational databases/algebra: primary key, normalization, etc. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you need. please apologize if there is a typo or something as I write it in notepad++.

```
with T as --This table contain only the min datetime of each person.
(
    select n.person_id, min(n.start_date) personMinDate, min(l.start_date) legMinDate
    from per_name n
    join per_leg_data l on l.person_id = n.person_id
    group by n.person_id
)
update leg

  -- this part replace your leg start date with your person min date
  set leg.start_date = T.personMinDate 

from per_leg_data leg

-- this join will give you only the correct row of the leg record.
join T on T.person_id = leg.person_id and T.legMinDate = leg.start_date 

-- this filter make this is only executed when necessary.
where leg.start_date <> T.personMinDate;
```

Comment: i have to do this for all.. this is updating just one

Answer (score 0):

### rewrite the update query

iF there is no primary key in the table and data is sort by start_date(ascending order) then update query needed to rewrite as

If min(name.start_date) <> min(leg.start_date)
then
update per_leg_data
set start_date = (select distinct min(start_date)
from per_name pn
where pn.person_id=person_id)
and pn.start_date=(select distinct min(start_date） from per_name)